# How to get column names and concatenate the column names delimited by a comma that has value 'Y' for each row?

Tags: db2

For DB2

How do I get the column names that contain a 'Y' for each row and concatenate them into a comma-delimited list?

For example, when the base table looks like this:

```
person | apple | orange | grapes
--------------------------------
1        Y        Y
2                 Y
3                          Y
```

The query result needs to look like this:

```
person  | fruits
---------------------------
1         apple,orange
2         orange
3         grapes
```

I tried `COALESCE`, but that didn't work, as it would coalesce into Y.

I tried  `CASE WHEN f.apple ='Y' THEN 'apple'
               WHEN f.orange = 'Y' THEN 'orange'
               WHEN f.grapes = 'Y' THEN 'grapes'
      END AS fruits`

but the above would only give return one of the WHEN statements.

I tried   `CASE WHEN f.apple ='Y' THEN concat('apple,')
                   WHEN f.orange = 'Y' THEN concat('orange,')
                   when f.grapes = 'Y' THEN concat('grapes,')
           END AS fruits`

but that doesn't work obviously because it's a syntax error (rather new to SQL) and still, only one of the `WHEN`s would work.

Answer (score 0):

The `LISTAGG` aggregate function will make quick work of this task if the values for each person can be represented as a multi-row expression:

```
WITH fruitCTE (person, fruitname) AS (
    SELECT person, 'apple' FROM originalTable WHERE apple = 'Y'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT person, 'orange' FROM originalTable WHERE orange = 'Y'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT person, 'grapes' FROM originalTable WHERE grapes = 'Y'
)
SELECT person, 
    LISTAGG( fruitname, ',' ) 
        WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY fruitname ASC )
    AS fruits  
FROM fruitCTE
GROUP BY person
;
```

If your query also needs to show people who have no Y flags at all, you can modify the final/outer `SELECT` to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from `originalTable` to `fruitCTE` on the `person` column.